# Is it fine to make a poster on a topic in which I have an article under review?

Tags: publications, ethics, poster

Next week I am going on a summer school meeting where the organizers encourage us to bring a poster. I would like to make a poster on a topic that I have covered in an article that is currently under review. Is that fine?

The rules of the conference to which the article is submitted state that I cannot submit any paper that covers the same material to any journal, conference or workshop. Does a poster count as a paper in this context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically this would be okay, because the poster is not published.

If in doubt, contact the PC chair of the conference to make sure.

Comment: I see, putting it on my website later would not be acceptable though, would it?

Comment: The poster? Putting it on your website is *not* publishing it.

Comment: Is putting the paper without being published in any journal counted as publising it?

Comment: @Ooker: What are you saying? And to whom?

Comment: @DaveClarke to you. I mean, if I write a paper, but never send it to any journal, just upload in my website, would it be considered as publishing?

Comment: @Ooker: No. (Presumably, you are not an academic publisher.)

Comment: Ok. Just for curious, if I am a publisher myself, will it count?

Comment: If you were a publisher and you posted it the web pages for an electronic journal that you happen to have, then it would be considered as published.

Answer (score 1):

I am also writing a paper in CS domain BT I can use the same name somewhere else. So you can use a poster related to your paper. Just check the rules ones. Mine doesn't say anything like that.

Comment: I meant I am writing  a paper in computer science domain. My journal didn't have any kind of rules as such yours. I even used the same name of my paper as an article for my research. I hope it seems clear now.